# Powershell parse get-winevent into csv with headers including all child objects

Tags: parsing, powershell

I am using Powershell 4 and trying to parse an archived event log into a csv file that includes all of the data and has headers associated with them. The closest I have been able to come is by using the following command:

```
    Get-WinEvent -Path .\Security.evtx |Select-Object TimeCreated, ProviderName, Id, Message, Level, Keyword, UserID, Data, Subject, SubjectUserSid, SubjectUserName, SubjectLogonId, ComputerName | Export-Csv .\Logging.csv
```

This gives me all the header information for all of the fields in the csv file but the only fields that contain data are TimeCreated, ProviderName, ID, Level, & Message. I am trying to get the missing data into columns also but not succeeding. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nice to see you found a solution.  Could you copy that to an answer for your own question & mark as the accepted answer; that way this question will be flagged as resolved.  Thank-you in advance.

Comment: I would have assumed ` | Select-Object -Property *` would have done the trick

Comment: `| Select-Object -Property *` object would not do this because you might also pipe the concerned objects (which contain properties with multiple lines including new line characters as `Carriage Return` and `Line Feed`) to another object that *does* support multiple line fields (think of cmdlets like `| Out-GridView`, `| ConvertTo-JSON` or almost any other function or cmdlet). **CSV files** just do not support multi-line fields due their plain text format.

Answer (score 2):

**This was copied from an edit to the question itself, and should be credited to the original question author**

Ok, I finally figured it out...At least for what I need to accomplish. Hopefully this will help someone.

```
    Get-WinEvent -Path .\Security.evtx | select TimeCreated, ProviderName, Id, @{n='Message';e={$_.Message -replace '\s+', " "}} | Export-Csv .\Logging.csv
```

This code allows you to export the archived eventlog into csv with headers and puts the whole message body into one cell, which allows import into a database with ease when you have no tools to work with.

Comment: @glennsl: I am not looking for the credits but simply want to progress the open question and get it out of the `Unanswered` list as requested by [JohnLBevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan) 4 month ago. I guess there is no way to change the owner of the answer to [@user3571026](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3571026/user3571026) or maybe to a kind of anonymous account that does accept votes. Meaning that if the owner doesn't react the question will stay unanswered forever, or not?

Comment: I think you can mark the answer as a community wiki somehow, or alternatively flag it for moderator attention to get them to do it. I didn't mean to imply that anything should be taken away from you, however, just wanted to point out that the "I" here refers to the OP, not to you (which would be equally valid if the answer is turned into a community wiki)